# Как работает передача store в props?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Изучаю react-redux. Объясните пожалуйста, как работает этот паттерн (передача store в props дочерних компонентов).

index.js:

```js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import App from './App';

const store = createStore((state = [], action) => { });

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js:

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends Component {
  render() { 
    return <div></div>;
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({ testStore: state }), dispatch => ({}))(App);
```

Особенно непонятна последняя строчка в App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `connect` обеспечивает "соединение" компонента и хранилища. Она предоставляет обертку над компонентом, который указывается в скобках в конце (Арр в данном случае), предоставляя ему подписку на изменение определенной части хранилища (первый аргумент) и действиям, которые можно вызвать напрямую через props в компоненте App (второй аргумент).
Таким образом, предположим, что у нас store состоит из нескольких редьюсеров (объединенных функцией combineReducers)

```
combineReducers({
  testStore1,
  testStore2
})
```

например, подписаться на изменение только testStore1 можно следующим образом:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { testStore1: state.testStore1 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoApp)
```

чтобы вызывать изменения состояния, необходимо подключить к компоненту действия - actions.

```
import * as actionCreators from './actionCreators'

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch) }
}
```

с помощью функции `bindActionCreators` созданные вами действия оборачиваются функцией dispatch, обеспечивающий возможность напрямую вызывать из Арр изменения состояния. Те действия, которые не вошли  в actionCreators, соответственно доступны внутри Арр не будут.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

ну и в конце создаем оболочку над нашим Арр, таким образом активизируем нашу подписку на изменения хранилища и доступ к изменениям хранилища.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень интересно)